# Coordinating Conjunction "FOR," in particular, AND commas

Tags: prepositions, commas, conjunctions

I have received instruction that coordinating conjunctions that begin a sentence should always be immediately followed by a comma.

I do not find another thread in this forum which answers my 2 specific questions, or even helps elucidate them.

Question 1) I cannot think of a single example where coordinating conjunction "For," at the beginning of a sentence, would be immediately followed by a comma. Can you?

Question 2) Is it true that, for the 6 CC besides "For," in all instances where a CC is the first word of a sentence, that CC is immediately followed by a comma?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commas after coordinating conjunctions at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358058/commas-after-coordinating-conjunctions-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence) You might also wish to look at Pitarou's answer and especially the linked article at [conjunction puzzle - is this clause dependent or independent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115821/conjunction-puzzle-is-this-clause-dependent-or-independent/115827#115827).

Comment: ... Essentially, it 'explodes the myth of FANBOYS'; these seven words do not form a homogeneous group. Far from it, as CGEL explains. And in fact, the Wikipedia article on 'coordinating conjunctions' suggests other candidates (8, 9, 10 ...) (eg 'only' as in 'I would go, only I don't have time') that could be added to this mixed assemblage.

Comment: @Yosef I'm assuming that that wasn't a wry attempt at an example from OP; it didn't add to the question. It's gone. // I'll tack on that parentheticals give false-positives: 'For, in spite of all the warnings, he persisted in skiing off-piste'. (Are there still people who say that starting a sentence with a 'CC' is a mortal sin?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have yet to see a legitimate use of *for* as a coördinating conjunction. How can you use *for* to connect two noun phrases when for example composing a compound subject? Not even the OED itself shows any uses of *for* as a coördinating conjunction.  And so I disbelieve—or rather, I shall continue to believe all this to be some figmentational mythunderstanding until and unless it should someday be  demonstrably proven otherwise. *Quod **erit** demonstrandum* and all that future jazz.

Comment: "For" belongs to just two parts of speech: a preposition, as in _This is for you_, and a clause subordinator, as in _For John to lose his temper like that is highly unusual_. Note that the _for_ infinitival clause is in front position in that example where it functions as subject. By contrast the coordinator "and" can occur in front position: A: _Ed is a good teacher_. B: _And his students really like him_.

Comment: *I have received instruction that coordinating conjunctions that begin a sentence should always be immediately followed by a comma.* And what they instructed you was wrong. <- note the lack of a comma after "and".

Comment: @tchrist This gets back to the definition of 'dependent clause': grammatically or logically/syntactically dependent. 'He had softly and suddenly vanished away – 
Ø the Snark was a Boojum, you see.'

Comment: @BillJ: What does CGEL call the *for* that means *because*? *Ed's students really like him, for he is a good teacher.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat A preposition,with the same meaning as "because".